# Excel date/time difference

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I would like to work out the current time since a date and time specified.

If the specified data is : `19/01/2013 16:44:00`
and now the time is : `19/01/2013 16:45:00`

the difference is 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 1 minute 0 seconds

This can be done easily just by taking the current time and minus the previous time and format it but this is hard to crunch data so what I wish to do is break each date/time segment into its own cell

Let's say cell A1 has the previous time and cell A2 has the current time

Cells a5 trough f5 would contain 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 1 minute 0 seconds

On a second note on this question is it possible to force the `=NOW()` to update every x seconds via VBA without interaction?

Comment: You should split this into two questions to avoid collision of answers of the different parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `YEAR` function to get year difference because that will give 1 year between 31st December 2012 and 1st Jan 2013 when there is only one day.....

....similarly you can have problems with MONTH and DAY (e.g. MONTH always returns a number between 1 and 12 whereas in this context you would only expect numbers between 0 and 11)

Try `DATEDIF` for the first 3 then `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND` as Justin suggests

Assuming start date/time in A2 and end date/time in B2 try these formulas respectively for Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds

`=DATEDIF(A2,B2-(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(B2,1)),"y")`

`=DATEDIF(A2,B2-(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(B2,1)),"ym")`

`=DATEDIF(A2,B2-(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(B2,1)),"md")`

`=HOUR(B2-A2)`

`=MINUTE(B2-A2)`

`=SECOND(B2-A2)`

format all cells as general

You may get some discrepancies because of variable month/year lengths......

Comment: for =HOUR(B2-A2)

=MINUTE(B2-A2)

=SECOND(B2-A2) i am getting #NUM!

Comment: If you get #NUM! error that means the dates are the wrong way round, I was assuming that B2 was later than A2, if not switch to `=HOUR(A2-B2)` etc

Answer (score 1):

Use `A5 = Year(A1)-Year(A2)` etc.

Using

`Year(...)`
`Month(...)`
`Day(...)`
`Hour(...)`
`Minute(...)`
`Second(...)`

For more details on creating a self-updating sheet based on a timer, look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867225/how-do-i-show-a-running-clock-in-excel) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon) and set a timer to execute the `Worksheet.Calculate` method.

Comment: i tried this with a1=30/01/2013 16:44:00
 and a2 = 30/01/2013 18:34:35
 and i get (days 0)(hours 2)(Minutes -10)(seconds 35) how would i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    DoDateA
End Sub

Sub DoDateA()
    Dim D1 As Date, D2 As Date, DC As Date, DS As Date
    Dim CA: CA = Array("", "yyyy", "m", "d", "h", "n", "s", "s")
    Dim Va%(7), Da(7) As Date, Ci%
    D1 = Now + Rnd() * 420  ' vary the  * factors for range of dates
    D2 = Now + Rnd() * 156
    If D1 > D2 Then
        [b4] = "Larger"
    Else
        [b4] = " smaller"
        DS = D1
        D1 = D2
        D2 = DS
    End If
    [d4] = D1
    [e4] = D2
    DC = D2
    For Ci = 1 To 6
        Va(Ci) = DateDiff(CA(Ci), DC, D1)
        DC = DateAdd(CA(Ci), Va(Ci), DC)
        Va(Ci + 1) = DateDiff(CA(Ci + 1), DC, D1)
        If Va(Ci + 1) < 0 Then  ' added too much
            Va(Ci) = Va(Ci) - 1
            DC = DateAdd(CA(Ci), -1, DC)
            Cells(9, Ci + 3) = Va(Ci + 1)
            Cells(8, Ci + 3) = Format(DC, "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss")
        End If
        Da(Ci) = DC
        Cells(5, Ci + 3) = CA(Ci)
        Cells(6, Ci + 3) = Va(Ci)
        Cells(7, Ci + 3) = Format(Da(Ci), "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss")
        Cells(10, Ci + 3) = DateDiff(CA(Ci), D2, D1)
    Next Ci
End Sub
```