# Calculate difference in hours between two datetime columns in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I have two columns in excel with datetime values and I want to get the difference between those two columns in hours.

If I try to subtract these two dates, I get #VALUE! in the resulting cell.

I tried to use datedif function of excel but it also gave me #VALUE! in the result cell.

I do not know how to get the difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel date/time difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609987/excel-date-time-difference)

Comment: Both have time format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a `#VALUE!` error when simply substracting the dates, it means that at least one of those values is actually not a date but probably just a string. You may need to convert them to `Date` first.

To check if Excel thinks of your value as of date, try to set a different format of the date, or call a =DAY(yourCell) function on it. If it returns a number, it is a date, if it returns `#VALUE!`, it is not.

Comment: Yes. For one column, I got the number and for another I got #Value!. How to convert the second column to proper date format?

Comment: That depends on the text. The DATEVALUE() function might help, but you may still need to search a bit.