# stop timer in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write a macro code to get the given time as input in the format (HH:MM:SS). and then it should run the time in background at the end of the time it should display a message as "time over". after giving some input or time again it restarts from the given time. kindly suggest

Comment: This local article [How do I show a running clock in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867225/how-do-i-show-a-running-clock-in-excel) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a cell and name it as **rngElapseTime**
2. Format the **rngElapseTime** cell as Time with the Type as HH:MM:SS
3. Go to Developer --> ViewCode
4. Copy and paste the code below.

That's it. Every time, a user changes the value in the rngElapseTime, the timer in the code below restarts and will prompt user with TimeOver when it times up.

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
>     If Target.Address = Range("rngElapseTime").Address Then        
>      nextScheduledTime = Now + TimeValue(Format(Target.Value, "HH:MM:SS"))
>      Application.OnTime nextScheduledTime, "TimeOver"    
>     End If            
> End Sub
>
>
> Public Sub TimeOver()    
>     MsgBox "Time Over", vbInformation            
> End Sub
> ```