# MatLab-MS Access 2010 database

Tags: database, matlab, ms-access, ms-access-2010, matlab-figure

Okay, I already asked this but the answer isn't what I really needed.

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756140/matlab-to-microsoft-access-database-2010-date-and-time).

the code for MatLab:

`clipboard('copy', datestr(now));`

and for the MS Access:

```
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String
Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = MyData.GetText
```

This code uses clipboard which is basic and limited. What I really need is direct transfer of data from MatLab to MS Access 2010. As I will hit a pushbutton with certain callback, the data that will appear in the GUI textbox will be recorded in MS Access too.

**For Example**

[image]

the code for the **Show Date and Time Checkbox** is:

```
m=1;
while m==1
m=get(hObject,'value');
txt=datestr(now);
set(handles.text7,'string',txt);
pause(1);
end
```

the **send/input date and time to DB Pushbutton** is blank. This pushbutton is where I will need the callback/code to make the date and time be recorded into the database.

This will be my first time to use MatLab to MS Access 2010 database and I'm still not that good. Please help me Gods of MatLab :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

well, i've never done or tried this, but perhaps this will give you some hints:

[Interprocess Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_pipes_for_ipc)

[sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200998/sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows)

another way, of course would be to use just a file, writing to it from Matlab and reading it with MS Access. depending on what type of data you want to share, this could be a fast to implement but slow in terms of process-time.

Comment: I'm pretty clueless on how to use this process. Can you please give me a brief example on how to do this process. A code will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, but as i said: i've never done this by my own. those links contain some methods that should work for you, but you have to try them by yourself. btw: what about using a file as a first try. this should work without hacking around...

Comment: what file are you referring to?

Comment: no, I mean: you can use a file to share the data between the processes