# Prompt user if they want to save after 5 minutes of activity

Tags: excel, vba

After a new file has been open for **5 minutes**, I want to ask the user if they want to save the file.

I found the code to ask them if they want to save (below), I just do not know how to modify to

1. Have the macro run on every new workbook
2. Have the prompt display after 5 minutes.

**Code**

```
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then 
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save the file before continuing?",vbYesNo,"Save?") = vbYes Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a timer to the workbook. See this thread:
[VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon)

E.g.

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")'Adds 5 minutes
Application.OnTime alertTime, "YOUR MACRO SUB"
```

To summarise:

1. Add a sub e.g. on Workbook open event that runs the timer running a separate Sub
2. In the separate Sub add the messagebox and the run the initial sub

Comment: Awesome - thank you!  Here is my next issue - I need to have this macro run on every new workbook on my boss' computer.  I am not sure how/where to save this to ensure it launches.  Thank you!!

Comment: Search the topic of Excel Add-ins. Excel Add-ins places in the "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns" are files that will open together with every Excel workbook on the workstation. In the Add-in add your macro to the Private Sub Workbook_Open() method but reference the "Activeworkbook" not the current workbook. Here is my fav tutorial on Add-ins http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Comment: Well I gave it my best shot and after an hour I could not get it to work.