# In Excel vba, how to achieve timer function

Tags: vba, excel, timer

What I thought would be quick excel vba, doesn't seem to be quick anymore. Basically, i want to loop through a set of questions within a given time. when the given time has expired or all questions completed, exit the loop (close the form and return). BTW, would like to show a timer countdown on the form as well. is it possible to achieve it?

I can get a form to show questions with answer options but not sure how to add the time criteria.

Comment: Lots of answers on this site, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon) for example...

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, this is not an ease task to achieve. Briefly speaking, one of the possible ways to do it is:
1. write your own class module for this program
2. create a form with questions, through the form constructor (Form_Initialize) create a new instance of your class (from point 1.) and link it to the form through variables, in addition your form needs to have variables to pass the information supplied by user at a later stage (your questions) to the object behind for storing
3. when your class is instantiated, the object will have a piece of code that contains a timer, and this timer will fire events, let's say, every second to refresh your form (to show how much time is left for answering questions), see UserForm.Repaint method. The questions that have been answered so far would be re-inserted into the form on repaint (info should be stored in your class object, then re-used to update the form through timer events).

Check this link as a starting point:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264327.aspx

or search for: RaiseEvent Statement in Excel Help (in VB Editor).

To see how to create vba classes:
http://www.cimaware.com/resources/article_39.html

In general, you need to search for information on how to:
create class modules,
separate object model (instantiated class) from the form,
pass information between the form and the model,
make the model to repaint your form at regular intervals (firing events)

Answer (score -1):

I think Application.OnTime method may can help.

[Scheduling Events With OnTime And Windows Timers](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx)

---updated---

As requested in comment section, I include the essential part on how the function works

```
        'variable to keep time interval the timer run again
        Public RunWhen As Double

         'main function that kick off the exam
        Public Sub startExam()

             'a label display how much time left, says start with 60 seconds
             DisplayTime.Caption = "60"

             'call a function that load and display question on screen
             'assume call LoadQuestion again when user provided quiz answer, not  implemented
             LoadQuestion (1)

             'start the 
             call Timer()

        End Sub



        'the timer function repeat itself
        Sub Timer()

                'set the next run time for Timer function
                RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

                'set the schedule 
                Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:="Timer", Schedule:=True


                'update the time left on screen
                UserForm1.DisplayTime.Caption = UserForm1.DisplayTime.Caption - 1

                'if the time deduced to 0, stop the schedule and alert user
                If UserForm1.DisplayTime.Caption = "0" Then
                    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:="Timer", chedule:=False
                    MsgBox "TimesUp"
            End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: Links can decay and there's no guarantee the linked page will be present in a year's time or whatever. Please consider summarizing the key points from the linked page in your answer, Stack Overflow answers should stand on their own merits without relying on external information.