# Settting .RefreshPeriod for an ADOBD SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that connects to SQL and pulls data from a table.  I used the macro recorder and SQL import wizard to do this, however I now need to be able to write the data back to SQL so I came across this post and have been trying to make the below code work.  It works fine, however I need to tweak it so it refreshes the data every minute so users are seeing data in near real time.

In the macro I recorded I was able to set a .RefreshPeriod = 1 parameter so the data would update, how can I do that here?

(Note: there are other functions dependent on the variables in here so I need to keep it somewhat the same - here is write up with [full code](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10392.editing-an-sql-server-table-in-excel)).

```
' General variables we'll need
Public con As ADODB.Connection
Public bIgnoreChange As Boolean
Dim pk As New Collection
Dim oldValue As Variant
Dim nRecordCount As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    ' Let's retrieve the data from the SQL Server table with the same name as the sheet
    bIgnoreChange = True
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Provider = "sqloledb"
    sConnectionString = "Server=CONDO-HTPC;Database=Strat_sample;Trusted_Connection=yes;" ';UID="";Pwd="" "
    con.Open sConnectionString


    ' Clean up old Primary Key
    While (pk.Count > 0)
        pk.Remove 1
    Wend

    ' Try to retrieve the primary key information
    On Error GoTo NoCon
    Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND tc.TABLE_NAME = '" & Sh.name & "'")


'Disable eventchange trigger in Workbook_SheetChange sub while this runs
Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Fill up the primary key infomration
    While (Not rs.EOF)
        pk.Add CStr(rs(0))
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Clean up the sheet's contents
    Sh.UsedRange.Clear

    ' Now get the table's data
    Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & Sh.name)


    ' Set the name of the fields
    Dim TheCells As Range
    Set TheCells = Sh.Range("A1")
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        TheCells.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).name
    Next i

    ' Get value for each field
    nRow = 1
    While (Not rs.EOF)
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            TheCells.Offset(nRow, i).Value = rs(i)
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
        nRow = nRow + 1
    Wend
    nRecordCount = nRow - 1

    bIgnoreChange = (pk.Count = 0) And (nRecordCount > 0)




'Enable Workbook_SheetChange sub
Application.EnableEvents = True


    Exit Sub


NoCon:
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    'Enable Workbook_SheetChange sub
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an alternative method if you want constant data refreshing on it would to be to look at something like [Data Nitro](https://datanitro.com/). This uses python in Excel and has the ability to update data live. (Also I'm in no way affiliated with data nitro)

Comment: This seems pretty simple from the few write ups I read.  I'm in the middle of learning R, VBA, and SQL so I don't have time for Python right now but will revisit this in the spring when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do. As described in the answer for following Stackoverflow question, you can set a macro to run at intervals using Application.OnTime. After the macro runs, you set another wait period so it runs again.

[VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon)

Also, make sure to turn off screen updating while the data is being refreshed.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Last, you should still be able to run this query if you set it up as a query table using the connection string. Then you just set the refresh rate and call it a day.

Comment: That was pretty painless, thanks for reply and the tip on turning off screen updating (I made sure to turn it back on at the end of the sub).