# Saving an Open Excel File programmatically

Tags: windows, excel, automation

I am looking to Save an Open Excel File programmatically without any user interaction. 
This could be a Script running as Scheduled task, or running as a windows service.
Can you please guide me in the direction which I can then work on?

Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this with just excel and it's macros.

In essence you simply just need to save the book every x seconds. So in order to do something every x seconds, starting from when the workbook is open, you do this: (Put that code in for when the workbook opens)

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
```

Then just have a macro in the workbook called "EventMacro" that will repeat it.

```
Public Sub EventMacro()
    '... Execute your actions here'
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```

For the '... Execute your actions here': You can use the line: `ActiveWorkbook.Save` to save your current excel sheet.

This should accomplish what you're looking for.

Previous answer this is based on [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon) and documentation for saving [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585.aspx)

Comment: Wow. This is really helpful. I will give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: @sdeshpande Okay! Remember to accept if it works/is the solution.

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot @Link