# Vba Stopwatch unintendently resets back 0 when changing other cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, stopwatch

I have a VBA stopwatch in my Excel spreadsheet, code:

```
Public StopIt As Boolean
Public ResetIt As Boolean
Public LastTime
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StartTime, FinishTime, TotalTime, PauseTime
StopIt = False
ResetIt = False
If Range("C2") = 0 Then
  StartTime = Timer
  PauseTime = 0
  LastTime = 0
Else
  StartTime = 0
  PauseTime = Timer
End If
StartIt:
  DoEvents
  If StopIt = True Then
    LastTime = TotalTime
    Exit Sub
  Else
    FinishTime = Timer
    TotalTime = FinishTime - StartTime + LastTime - PauseTime
    TTime = TotalTime * 100
    HM = TTime Mod 100
    TTime = TTime \ 100
    hh = TTime \ 3600
    TTime = TTime Mod 3600
    MM = TTime \ 60
    SS = TTime Mod 60
    Range("C2").Value = Format(hh, "00") & ":" & Format(MM, "00") & ":" & Format(SS, "00") & "." & Format(HM, "00")
    If ResetIt = True Then
      Range("C2") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
      LastTime = 0
      PauseTime = 0
      End
    End If
    GoTo StartIt
  End If
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  StopIt = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Range("C2").Value = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
  LastTime = 0
  ResetIt = True
End Sub
```

This stopwatch works correctly. My problem is that when I change a cell in my spreadsheet or make any changes it resets the stopwatch to '0'.

I want it to run throughout my session as I have other cells which refer to this counter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I could not find any similar problems while searching for a solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Which value resets to 0? Do you have any code in your `Worksheet_Change` event handler?

Comment: What do you want to happen if this code is called a second time and a stopwatch is currently active? Do you want to allow multiple stopwatches to run? I'm guessing, at a minimum, you need a flag to state 'HeyImActive'.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - Yep, just noticed that.  If CommandButton1 is clicked while it's "running", it restarts from the last time it was stopped.

Comment: I have no code for in the event change handler. I only want one value in my worksheet with the timer, I do not want multiple.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  The only bug I can replicate is the one mentioned above.

Comment: It part of a betting app. Where the timer should be referred in a Vlookup. That's why I don't want multiple values in multiple locations.

Comment: I'm not sure what "multiple locations" has to do with the issue you're describing. What ***exactly*** do you mean by "it resets the stopwatch to '0'"? When I run your code as posted, `C2` is displaying what I expect it should, `LastTime` is only zero'd when CommandButton3 is clicked, and changing cell contents on the worksheet doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is it a setting on my Excel preferences that's causing this then?

Comment: @Comintern, did you use a form for this? I just created a module and ran the code manually (after I added explicit variable definitions ... hint to OP: always use Option Explicit to save a lot of headaches one day).
When I manually changed any cell, the code stopped updating C2. I switched to a different sheet (and now the timer appears in C2 of that sheet) and any change stops the code. Not sure if this is Excel limitation or not. Wonder what happens if you have a pop-up form with only a timer?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - I was using ActiveX buttons on the Worksheet, but I just tried it on a modeless UserForm and it still doesn't reset when I change cells.

Comment: Could you lay out step by step what you are doing to get no reset? Could it be excel option settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have found a solution yet, but I did some research and think I know why your code doesn't work, and possibly have another solution... if acceptable...

When I test your code by starting the timer then changing any cell, it doesn't reset to zero but it does stop the timer. Looking at the code you have (which maybe came from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3684-excel-create-stopwatch.html), the code is only good for using a simple timer ... nothing else. And since it is never relinquishes control until you stop it, it uses a tremendous amount of your processor (take a look at Task Manager!)

I did find code here on Stack [VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon)  and used the second answer (simply too lazy to use first answer at startup).

You can now change cells and the code continues to run (except it 'pauses' while a change is being made to a cell). You may not like the fact that it increments by seconds, but maybe someone else knows a solution to that.

The code does NOT go in a sheet module.

```
Option Explicit

Dim TimerActive As Boolean
Sub StartTimer()
    Start_Timer
End Sub

Private Sub Start_Timer()
    TimerActive = True
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Timer"
End Sub

Private Sub Stop_Timer()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer()
    If TimerActive Then
        Activesheet.Cells(2, 3).value = Time
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Timer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this Wayne.