# Run VBA Function every 30 seconds (from startup)(Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

So i have my code that should be executed when i start my access DB 
(it imports files from a folder)

```
Function import_files
'all the code (works without errors)
end function
```

My idea was a Macro that runs on startup then opens the function and uses

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "import_files"
```

that of corse did not work because its not compatible with access... so you can use it like this:

```
Excel.Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "import_files"
```

just that u cant run anything from then on...

is there any simple short solution to this

someting basic like this

```
Function Import_files
do every 30 seconds 
run code
loop
end function
```

Thanks for any help!
(Im not that good in VBA :) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon)

Comment: @NelsonVides Not a dupe, that's Excel-specific code and won't work in Access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using the **Form's TimerInterval property**. You could open a form (hidden) and have the timer trigger the code.

**Example**
The following example shows how to create a flashing button on a form by displaying and hiding an icon on the button. The *form's Load event procedure sets the form's TimerInterval property* to 1000 so the icon display is toggled once every second.

```
Sub Form_Load() 
    Me.TimerInterval = 1000 
End Sub 

Sub Form_Timer() 
    Static intShowPicture As Integer 
    If intShowPicture Then 
        ' Show icon. 
        Me!btnPicture.Picture = "C:\Icons\Flash.ico" 
    Else 
        ' Don't show icon. 
        Me!btnPicture.Picture = "" 
    End If 
    intShowPicture = Not intShowPicture 
End Sub
```

**To use this sample code:**
**Note:** Your screen will look different based on version you are using.
You can Google: access me.timerinterval examples.

1. Enable macros by clicking options | enable this content | OK.[image][image]
2. Create new blank form and view in design view.[image][image]
3. Add command button | cancel wizard | delete caption | name it btnPicture.[image][image][image]
   [image]
4. Add form event procedures.
   A. Deselect button and select form properties.
   B. Click event loader for form in the property sheet.
   C. Double click Code Builder.
   D. Select all and then paste code from here.
   [image]

[image]

---

**FYI:**
For the code mmehta did; you would put it in a module. 
He showed you how to extend on your thought process.
You suggested:

```
Function Import_files
    do every 30 seconds 
    run code
    if needed reset any variables
```

> ```
>         myVariableInteger = 0
>         myVariableString = ""
>         myVariableString= vbNullString
>         myVariableInteger = Null
>         Set myVariableObject = Nothing
> ```

```
    loop
end function
```

He elaborated:

```
Function Import_files
  Do
    Pause(30)
    run code (You're code here or better yet put your code in a sub routine and call the routine.)
  Loop
End Function
```

---

1. Put this code in a module

   ```
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
   On Error GoTo Error_GoTo

   Dim PauseTime As Variant
   Dim Start As Variant
   Dim Elapsed As Variant

   PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
   Start = Timer
   Elapsed = 0
   Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
       Elapsed = Elapsed + 1
       If Timer = 0 Then
           ' Crossing midnight
           PauseTime = PauseTime - Elapsed
           Start = 0
           Elapsed = 0
       End If
       DoEvents
   Loop

   Exit_GoTo:
       On Error GoTo 0
       Exit Function
   Error_GoTo:
       Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl
       GoTo Exit_GoTo
   End Function

   Sub msgUser()
       Dim x As Integer
       x = MsgBox("Click 'OK' to continue.", vbOKOnly, "Ready?")
   End Sub
   ```
2. Place your cursor in the routine Pause and press play.[image]
3. Watch the msgBox pop up every 30 seconds.

Comment: How can i use this for kind of a loop then? as im trying to let the function run every 30 seconds from the beginning on...

Comment: The code "Me.TimerInterval = 1000" is the loop.  1000=1sec. Thus, 30000=30seconds. "Me.TimerInterval = 30000"

Comment: oh okay so I can then use the sub From_timer and put my code in there but how does it then run it and start over again? (as I sayed im not that good at VBA sorry)

Comment: hi @sunsetsurf thanks for this awesome instruction!
the Pause function part works perfect!
i do then get an error tho from the module after the caled function has endet... i get this errormessage: Subscript out of range (Error 9)
any idea how i can fix this last part? :)

Comment: i kind of fixed the error but i found out that it does not loop "infinitif"
the function just ends... i tryed it with an goto above the pause(time) and eaven I tryed to call the makro again what also didn't work... :( any idea?

Comment: Did you alter the code, or include it with other code? "Subscript out of range" is an index of an array or collection doesn't exist; ex: array index range is 0-9, but 1-10 was called.

Comment: i just goth it runing <3 XD now its onl my code that has to reset all the variables after the loop :) do you know how i do that?^^ thanks for everithing man!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function for timer.

```
Function Import_files
      Do
            Pause(30)
            run code
      Loop
end function

Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
    On Error GoTo Error_GoTo

    Dim PauseTime As Variant
    Dim Start As Variant
    Dim Elapsed As Variant

    PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
    Start = Timer
    Elapsed = 0
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        Elapsed = Elapsed + 1
        If Timer = 0 Then
            ' Crossing midnight
            PauseTime = PauseTime - Elapsed
            Start = 0
            Elapsed = 0
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

Exit_GoTo:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
Error_GoTo:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl
    GoTo Exit_GoTo
End Function
```