# Excel Randbetween - Refresh without Shift-F9

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to have an excel worksheet automatically calculate a rand between function without having to hit shift f9 or calculate the workbook/worksheet.

I'm looking to do this in order to create some animated conditional formatting, but the rand between function won't update automatically even when auto calculate is turned on.

Comment: The `Randbetween()` updates every time I enter new data with my spreadsheet. What do you mean?

Comment: The key is you have to either enter new data or hit refresh. I want it to change with no input at all from the user. Same issue with the Now formula.

Comment: Do you want the refresh to occur every second or every minute or what ???????????

Comment: When there is an event - volatile functions get re-calculated, if there is no event (entering new data or refreshing)  then there is no need to re-calculate. You could write a macro to force recalculate every 20 seconds or duration you prefer....

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing there's a way to have a vb script file at regular intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing a VB script to automatically do something to the spreadsheet using this example:

[VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon#4348132)

This basically made all of the formulas update without the user doing anything (entering data or calculating).

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code in a standard module:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 1
Public Const cRunWhat = "The_Sub"

Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
     schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub The_Sub()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub
```

This implements 1 second auto-re-calculation:

- to begin, run `StartTimer`
- to stop, run `StopTimer`

Adapted from [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OnTime.aspx)