# Increment a cell value with a timer

Tags: excel, vba

Kindly help me on solving the following requirement.

In my sheet , say in cell `A1` the value of the cell needs to be incremented by `1` till it equals the value of `B1`. Cell `B1` value would be `10`.

When Incremental value of cell `A1` reaches `10`, the incremental loop needs to restart from `1` again. The value of cell `A1` should increment every minute.

I have tried the this with the following formula. I have a macro to refresh excel by 1 minute.
`=IF((a1+1)<=b1,(a1+1),1)`
Works fine but returns the circular reference error. So I was wondering whether VBA can do this for me in background

Regards
Dilan

Comment: Post your refresh code here. Need to insert code inside time.

Comment: Find something useful here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need VBA to do that. You need to check value of `A1` and compare it with `B1` then increment or restart value of `A1`. Try below sub. You have to insert below codes inside your refresh sub.

```
Sub inc()
    If Range("A1") < Range("B1") Then
        Range("A1") = Range("A1") + 1
    Else
        Range("A1") = 1
    End If
End Sub
```